# Unable to store object in Django cache because the model uses a dynamic attribute

Tags: django, caching

I am using the [django-stdimage](https://github.com/codingjoe/django-stdimage) package to auto-resize my images. However, it seems that this particular plugin creates problems when I want to cache certain results.

Models:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = StdImageField(upload_to="images", variations={"thumbnail": (800, 600), delete_orphans=True)
```

View:

```
page = Page.objects.get(pk=1)
cache.set("page", page, None)
```

Result:

> AttributeError:
>
> 'StdImageFieldFile' object has no attribute 'thumbnail'

From [here](https://github.com/codingjoe/django-stdimage/issues/68):

> that is because the attribute is being set dynamically and is not
> properly serialised.

So my question is: is there a way to record this object in the cache, even though this specific attribute is being set dynamically? Note that I don't need that specific field to be cached - if there is a way to cache the entire object WITHOUT the image field, I am happy with that too. I have also tried:

```
page = Page.objects.defer("image").get(pk=1)
```

But somehow this doesn't take out the image field from the caching operation.

Comment: Which version of `django-stdimage` are you using? I have the feeling that this issue was fixed in version 5.3.2 : https://github.com/codingjoe/django-stdimage/commit/10de7724f913f711b620070976253a0807d753e8

Comment: Using version 6.0.1...